# Confusion matrix with labels plot in matplotlib not organized properly

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, confusion-matrix

I'm using the following code for plotting a confusion matrix:

```
labels = test_y.unique()
predictions = chosen_clf.predict(X=test_x)
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true=test_y, y_pred=predictions,     labels=labels)
conf_matrix = pd.DataFrame(conf_matrix, index=labels, columns=labels)
plt.figure()
sn.heatmap(conf_matrix, annot=True)
plt.savefig(r'confusion_matrix.png')
```

However, the plot im getting has a few problems:
 - the labels are cut
 - The grid isn't wide enough resulting with unreadable values, e.g. 2e+02 in the (1,1) position.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try adding `plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))` before calling `sn.heatmap()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

`plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))`

before line:

`sn.heatmap()`